# Is there a way to batch profile (ViewID) update queries?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working on getting our agency's analytics up to best practices and that will require bulk updating, creating, and modifying several analytics view ids.

Rather than having to manually update every view in analytics, I've been able to update a fair amount of them through the management api for google analytics.

The problem I run in to is that the write quota limit is set at 50 per day and at that rate it will literally take 27 days just to update the viewids and who knows how long to do the rest of the things I need to do.

For this particular problem, I've done individual queries to update the viewids that I have but rapidly hit the daily write quota.

I'm currently working on batching my queries using the BatchHttpRequest from the google api library but the query happens to quickly and it does not appear to actually reduce the number of queries that are happening.

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.BatchHttpRequest-class.html

I am trying this route as it is a recommended method of reducing queries when managing users and I was hoping I could see similar performance gains with data.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/user-management#batching

```
batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=call_back)

    #for every item in list put together update query
    for i in range(1, max_row+1):

        link = service.management().profiles().update(
            accountId=accountid,
            webPropertyId=propertyid,
            profileId=viewid,
            body={
                'name': 'Master View',
                'eCommerceTracking': True,
                'enhancedECommerceTracking': True,
                'currency': 'USD',
                'timezone': 'America/New_York',
                'websiteUrl': updatesite
            }
        )

        #Add query to batch httpquery
        batch.add(link)

        #keep track of what's been added to the batch
        print('adding ' + updatesite +
                ' to batch request for ' + propertyname)

    #verify the batch object and execute
    print(batch)

    batch.execute(http=None)
```

Expected: Updated Analytics profiles in as few queries as possible

Result:

Request 6 returned API error : 403 : Quota Error: Rate limit for writes exceeded.

then

Request 12 returned API error : 403 : Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded.

then

Request 1 returned API error : 403 Quota Error:  Quota Error: You have exceeded the maximum number of writes/day for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of fighting with the script, batching is not an option for inserting more than 50 calls data in to analytics per day.

I had to use Puppeteer to automate the bulk renaming of view names in analytics.